# How can I randomly place ImageButtons and prevent them from overlapping?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I want to create array for ImageButton to prevent the overlapping of my objects and I want to add it after params.height. So my question is how to do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    final Context context = this;
    MediaPlayer mplayer;
    MediaPlayer mplPlayer1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        /*
         * for-loop creates my imagebutton and then i place them in random
         * position but the problem is that its overlapping too much So how to
         * prevent it?
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            params.width = 83;
            params.height = 80;
            int left = (int) (Math.random() * 1024 + 83);
            int right = (int) (Math.random() * 600 + 20);
            if (left == 600 & right == 600) {
                params.setMargins(left, 10 + 2, right, 0);
            } else
                params.setMargins(left, 50 - 1, right, 0);
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            rl.addView(btn);
            btn.setId(i);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What i can't see your reply?

Comment: Have you considered attempting to record the position of each placed ImageButton and then ensuring they don't overlap?

Comment: Because i have created variable left and respektive right it's working but overlapping

Comment: Your `params` variable gives you the location of each button. If you were to store these in a `HashSet` then when you try and create a new `LayoutParams` you could loop over each value in the set and check if it overlaps with any existing buttons. If it does overlap you could simply try again.

Comment: Could you update your question with any additional libraries required to make it compile?

Comment: How to improve the question

Answer (score 0):

```
      int left = (int) (Math.floor((Math.random()*1024)/83.0) * 83 + 83);
      int right = (int) (Math.floor((Math.random()*600)/80.0)*80 + 20);
```

That would separate each random number by the width and height of the buttons.

Comment: It's not working because i can see only 7 objects not 10

Comment: try removing your +83 & +20, it might be pushing some objects off the screen

Comment: Its still overlapping